# Maximo Anywhere - cannot see field added to OSLC Resource

Tags: maximo-anywhere, oslc

I'm attempting to expose a new field to the OSLCWORKTYPE OSLC object in Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1, specifically in the additionalworktype resource used by the worktype lookup

After following the instructions http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/config_apps/t_add_flds_domains.html and reading the steps in this post [Incorporating Custom Fields into OSLC Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754292/incorporating-custom-fields-into-oslc-components) - I'm still having problems seeing the field in the app.

I've added it additionalworktype resource as below but when console logging it out, it's not shown in the object.  However when I query the rdf using Postman I can see the field returned in the response.   The field in question is **brdbwtcategory**

```
<!-- Work Type resource -->
    <resource additionalData="true" describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#WorkType" id="additionalworktype" name="additionalworktype" pageSize="100" providedBy="/oslc/sp/SmarterPhysicalInfrastructure">
        <attributes id="additionalworktype_attributes">
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:orgid" id="additionalworktype_orgid_spiorgid" index="true" isExactMatchIndex="true" name="orgid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:worktype" id="additionalworktype_worktype_spiworktype" index="true" name="worktype"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="dcterms:title" id="additionalworktype_wtypedesc_dctermstitle" index="true" name="wtypedesc"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:woclass" id="additionalworktype_woclass_spiwoclass" index="true" isExactMatchIndex="true" name="woclass"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:type" id="additionalworktype_type_spitype" index="true" isExactMatchIndex="true" name="type"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="dcterms:identifier" id="additionalworktype_worktypeid_dctermsidentifier" name="worktypeid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:brdbwtcategory" id="additionalworktype_worktypeid_spibrdbwtcategory" index="false" name="brdbwtcategory"/>
            <!-- <attribute name="startstatus" describedByProperty="spi:startstatus"
                /> -->
            <!-- <attribute name="completestatus" describedByProperty="spi:completestatus"
                /> -->
            <!-- <attribute name="promptdown" describedByProperty="spi:promptdown"
                /> -->
            <!-- <attribute name="promptfail" describedByProperty="spi:promptfail"
                /> -->
            <!-- <attribute name="keeptaskstatushist" describedByProperty="spi:keeptaskstatushist"
                /> -->
        </attributes>
        <queryBases id="additionalworktype_queryBases">
            <queryBase id="additionalworktype_queryBase_getworktype" name="getworktype" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcworktype"/>
        </queryBases>
        <whereClause id="additionalworktype_whereClause"/>
    </resource>
```

Lookup

```
            <lookup filterClass="application.handlers.WODetailHandler" filterMethod="filterWorktypeForLookup" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup" label="Select Work Type" resource="additionalworktype">
        <requiredResources id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_requiredResources">
            <requiredResource id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype" name="additionalworktype"/>
            <requiredResource id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_domainwoclass" name="domainwoclass"/>
        </requiredResources>
        <list id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_list" resource="additionalworktype">
            <searchAttributes id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_searchAttributes">
                <searchAttribute id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_searchAttribute_worktype" name="worktype"/>
                <searchAttribute id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_searchAttribute_wtypedesc" name="wtypedesc"/>
                <searchAttribute id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_searchAttribute_brdbwtcategory" name="brdbwtcategory"/>
            </searchAttributes>
            <listItemTemplate id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_listItemTemplate_Item1Desc1" layout="Item1Desc1">
                <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_worktype" layoutInsertAt="item1" resourceAttribute="worktype"/>
                <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_wtypedesc" layoutInsertAt="item2" resourceAttribute="wtypedesc"/>
                <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup__additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_brdbwtcategory" layoutInsertAt="item3" resourceAttribute="brdbwtcategory"/>
            </listItemTemplate>
        </list>
    </lookup>
```

Postman response

```
    {"spi:promptdown": false,
  "spi:contentuid": "9",
  "spi:promptfail": false,
  "spi:worktype": "FO",
  "dcterms:title": "Follow On",
  "spi:brdbwtcategory": "CM",
  "rdf:type": [
    {
      "rdf:resource": "http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#WorkType"
    }
  ],
  "spi:orgid": "TESTORG",
  "spi:woclass_description": "Work Order",
  "rdf:about": "http://xxxxx.xxx-xxx.xxx:32800/maximo/oslc/os/oslcworktype/_OQ--",
  "spi:keeptaskstatushist": true,
  "dcterms:identifier": "9",
  "prefixes": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "dcterms": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
    "spi": "http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#",
    "oslc": "http://open-services.net/ns/core#"
  },
  "_rowstamp": "1699854",
  "spi:woclass": "WORKORDER",
  "spi:brdbwtcategory_description": "Corrective Maintenance",
  "spi:type_description": "Not Applicable",
  "spi:type": "NONE"
}
```

The lookup view is only showing the Work Type

[Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyaBT.png)

I've run the anywhere-rdf-puller.xml and verified the field is in the oslc/shapes/oslcworktype file on the MobileFirst server

Am I missing something else in this process?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure your error is in the lookup.

Your code still uses the default **Item1Desc1** layout, but in the code you refer to **layoutInsertAt** item2 and item3 that don't exist in that layout. Like the name suggest (and also the default code) there is only a item1 and desc1 'field'  that can be filled.

```
<listItemTemplate id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_listItemTemplate_Item1Desc1" layout="Item1Desc1">
            <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_worktype" layoutInsertAt="item1" resourceAttribute="worktype"/>
            <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup_additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_wtypedesc" layoutInsertAt="item2" resourceAttribute="wtypedesc"/>
            <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="WorkExecution.WorkTypeLookup__additionalworktype_Item1Desc1_brdbwtcategory" layoutInsertAt="item3" resourceAttribute="brdbwtcategory"/>
</listItemTemplate>
```

You should create a new layout template under 
artifact/layouts/templates/small/
Just have a look at the examples there and it will make sense.